Unzip zipfile which contains subfolders stored in blob storage using Azure Data Factory
I want to extract all files and folders from a zipfile which is stored on an Azure Blob Storage. The extracted data should be stored in a output folder.
I have a zipfile stored in Azure Blob Storage. The zipfile contains a subfolder like so:
ExportPV.zip contains:
export/file1.csv
export/file2.csv
I have created a pipeline in Azure Data Factory with a copy data activity. For more info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFlOTJbE5pc
This method works for zipfiles which don't contain a subfolder. So this will work:
ExportPV2.zip contains:
file1.csv
file2.csv
Is there a way to extract the data including the folders from the zip file using Azure Data Factory?
I have tried the configuration suggested by @Bhavani, but I get this error:

Failure happened on 'Source' side.
ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedFileOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The
file operation is failed, upload file failed at path:
'perfectviewexport/Output/PerfectView_export_Inter-Rent20240617.zip/exports/alle
contactpersonen.csv'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.IO.InvalidDataException,Message=Found
invalid data while decoding.,Source=System,'

Find the configuration below:





You can follow below procedure to achieve your requirement:
Configure source data set with ZipDeflate compression type with zipfile path as shown below:

Configure Source in copy activity by checking Recursively as shown below:

Configure sink dataset up to container level. Debug the pipeline. The zip file will extract successfully with sub folder as shown below:

Here is the pipeline Json for your reference:
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings",
                            "compressionProperties": {
                                "type": "ZipDeflateReadSettings"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings"
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                            "quoteAllText": true,
                            "fileExtension": ".txt"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "typeConversion": true,
                        "typeConversionSettings": {
                            "allowDataTruncation": true,
                            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "zipsource",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "zipsink",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}


Hey @Bhavani
Thanks for your suggesiton. Unfortunetly I get an error:
Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedFileOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The file operation is failed, upload file failed at path: 'perfectviewexport/Output/PerfectView_export_Inter-Rent20240617.zip/exports/alle contactpersonen.csv'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.IO.InvalidDataException,Message=Found invalid data while decoding.,Source=System,'
This error only occurs with the zip files with subfolders.

select only PerfectView_export_Inter-Rent20240617.zip file in the source dataset don't select the file inside the zip file. That is the reason for getting above error.

Hey @Bhavani
I am selecting only the zip file. Please find a print screen in the edited original question. The path I select is: perfectviewexport/export/PerfectView_export_Inter-Rent20240617.zip

The error "Found invalid data while decoding" when unzipping files with subfolders usually indicates a corrupted ZIP file or unsupported compression methods. Verify the file's integrity, try using different unzipping tools, and ensure the file path lengths and permissions are appropriate.
